# Simple Hamiltonian Monte Carlo Example with TensorFlow Probability's Edward2

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-probability, edward

### Edward example

As [`Edward`](http://edwardlib.org/) is deprecated and requires an older version of TensorFlow one can create a dedicated virtual environment for the following example

```
$ python3 --version
Python 3.6.8
$ python3 -m venv edward
$ source edward/bin/activate
(edward) $ pip3 install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel
(edward) $ cat edward.txt
tensorflow==1.7
edward~=1.3
scipy~=1.2
pandas~=0.24
matplotlib~=3.0
(edward) $ pip3 install -r edward.txt
```

I have a *very* simple minimal working example of using Hamiltonian Monte Carlo with Edward called `edward_old.py`

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np
import scipy.stats
import tensorflow as tf
import edward as ed
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def generate_samples(data, n_samples):
    # Pick initial point for MCMC chains based on the data
    low, med, high = np.percentile(data, (16, 50, 84))
    mu_init = np.float32(med)
    t_init = np.float32(np.log(0.5 * (high - low)))

    # Build a very simple model
    mu = ed.models.Uniform(-1.0, 1.0)
    t = ed.models.Uniform(*np.log((0.05, 1.0), dtype=np.float32))
    X = ed.models.Normal(
        loc=tf.fill(data.shape, mu), scale=tf.fill(data.shape, tf.exp(t))
    )

    # Emperical samples of a sclar
    q_mu = ed.models.Empirical(params=tf.Variable(tf.fill((n_samples,), mu_init)))
    q_t = ed.models.Empirical(params=tf.Variable(tf.fill((n_samples,), t_init)))

    # Run inference using HMC to generate samples.
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        inference = ed.HMC({mu: q_mu, t: q_t}, data={X: data})
        inference.run(step_size=0.01, n_steps=10)
        mu_samples, t_samples = sess.run([q_mu.params, q_t.params])
    return mu_samples, t_samples


def visualize(samples, mu_grid, sigma_grid):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(6, 5))
    ax.scatter(samples['mu'], samples['sigma'], s=5, lw=0, c='black')
    ax.set_xlim(mu_grid[0], mu_grid[-1])
    ax.set_ylim(sigma_grid[0], sigma_grid[-1])
    ax.set_title('Edward')
    ax.set_xlabel('$\mu$')
    ax.set_ylabel('$\sigma$')
    plt.savefig('edward_old.pdf')


def main():
    np.random.seed(0)
    tf.set_random_seed(0)

    # Generate pseudodata from draws from a single normal distribution
    dist_mean = 0.0
    dist_std = 0.5
    n_events = 5000
    toy_data = scipy.stats.norm.rvs(dist_mean, dist_std, size=n_events)

    mu_samples, t_samples = generate_samples(toy_data, n_events)
    samples = pd.DataFrame({'mu': mu_samples, 'sigma': np.exp(t_samples)})

    n_grid = 50
    mu_grid = np.linspace(*np.percentile(mu_samples, (0.5, 99.5)), n_grid)
    sigma_grid = np.linspace(*np.exp(np.percentile(t_samples, (0.5, 99.5))), n_grid)
    visualize(samples, mu_grid, sigma_grid)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

which produces the plot below through

```
(edward) $ python3 edward_old.py
```

[image]

### Edward2 example

However, when I try to replicate it using [TensorFlow Probability](https://github.com/tensorflow/probability) and [Edward2](https://github.com/tensorflow/probability/tree/master/tensorflow_probability/python/edward2) with the following environment

```
$ python3 --version
Python 3.6.8
$ python3 -m venv tfp-edward2
$ source tfp-edward2/bin/activate
(tfp-edward2) $ pip3 install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel
(tfp-edward2) $ cat tfp-edward2.txt
tensorflow~=1.13
tensorflow-probability~=0.6
scipy~=1.2
pandas~=0.24
matplotlib~=3.0
(tfp-edward2) $ pip3 install -r tfp-edward2.txt
```

and the following changes from `edward_old.py`'s `generate_samples` in a file called `edward2.py`

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np
import scipy.stats
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_probability as tfp
from tensorflow_probability import edward2 as ed
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def generate_samples(data, n_samples):
    # Pick initial point for MCMC chains based on the data
    low, med, high = np.percentile(data, (16, 50, 84))
    mu_init = np.float32(med)
    t_init = np.float32(np.log(0.5 * (high - low)))

    def model(data_shape):
        mu = ed.Uniform(
            low=tf.fill(data_shape, -1.0), high=tf.fill(data_shape, 1.0), name="mu"
        )
        t = ed.Uniform(
            low=tf.log(tf.fill(data_shape, 0.05)),
            high=tf.log(tf.fill(data_shape, 1.0)),
            name="t",
        )
        x = ed.Normal(loc=mu, scale=tf.exp(t), name="x")
        return x

    log_joint = ed.make_log_joint_fn(model)

    def target_log_prob_fn(mu, t):
        """Target log-probability as a function of states."""
        return log_joint(data.shape, mu=mu, t=t, x=data)

    step_size = tf.get_variable(
        name='step_size',
        initializer=0.01,
        use_resource=True,  # For TFE compatibility
        trainable=False,
    )

    num_burnin_steps = 1000

    hmc_kernel = tfp.mcmc.HamiltonianMonteCarlo(
        target_log_prob_fn=target_log_prob_fn,
        num_leapfrog_steps=5,
        step_size=step_size,
        step_size_update_fn=tfp.mcmc.make_simple_step_size_update_policy(
            num_adaptation_steps=int(num_burnin_steps * 0.8)
        ),
    )

    # How should these be done?
    q_mu = tf.random_normal(data.shape, mean=mu_init)
    q_t = tf.random_normal(data.shape, mean=t_init)

    states, kernel_results = tfp.mcmc.sample_chain(
        num_results=n_samples,
        current_state=[q_mu, q_t],
        kernel=hmc_kernel,
        num_burnin_steps=num_burnin_steps,
    )

    # Initialize all constructed variables.
    init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()

    # Run the inference using HMC to generate samples
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        init_op.run()
        states_, results_ = sess.run([states, kernel_results])

    mu_samples, t_samples = states_[0][0], states_[1][0]
    return mu_samples, t_samples
```

Running with

```
(tfp-edward2) $ python3 edward2.py
```

shows that there are some obvious problems. I don't think I am formulating the equivalent of the `ed.models.Empirical` correctly, so if there are thoughts on that or anything else I am doing wrong that would be great.

I have tried to follow the "[Upgrading from Edward to Edward2](https://github.com/tensorflow/probability/blob/master/tensorflow_probability/python/edward2/Upgrading_From_Edward_To_Edward2.md)" examples already, but I haven't been able to understand them enough to transfer from the example used there of the `deep_exponential_family` model to this example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem I created for myself was totally messing up the shapes of my distributions. What I failed to properly grasp at first was that the `current_state` of my `tfp.mcmc.sample_chain` should have been scalars (`shape==()`) that represented the initial positions of the chains. Once I realized this, then it became clear that those positions, `q_mu` and `q_t` had quite the wrong shape and should be the mean of samples from the positions determined from the data

```py
q_mu = tf.reduce_mean(tf.random_normal((1000,), mean=mu_init))
q_t = tf.reduce_mean(tf.random_normal((1000,), mean=t_init))
```

As these values are scalars, then I had been creating the shapes of my model wrong as well. I had been creating samples of my random variables that were the same shape as my data mistakenly thinking that this was just moving the shaping of `x` to the shape of `mu` and `t`. Of course `mu` and `t` are meant to be scalar random variables from their respective Uniform distributions which then are the parameters for `x`'s Normal distribution from which `data.shape` samples are drawn.

```py
def model(data_shape):
    mu = ed.Uniform(low=-1.0, high=1.0, name="mu")
    t = ed.Uniform(low=tf.log(0.05), high=tf.log(1.0), name="t")
    x = ed.Normal(
        loc=tf.fill(data_shape, mu), scale=tf.fill(data_shape, tf.exp(t)), name="x"
    )
    return x
```

Once this is done the only thing left to do is to properly access the states now

```py
with tf.Session() as sess:
    init_op.run()
    states_, results_ = sess.run([states, kernel_results])
    mu_samples, t_samples = (states_[0], states_[1])
```

and that produces the image below with

```
(tfp-edward2) $ python3 edward2.py
```

which is a good match for the original using `Edward`.

[image]

The fully corrected script is below

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np
import scipy.stats
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_probability as tfp
from tensorflow_probability import edward2 as ed
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def generate_samples(data, n_samples):
    # Pick initial point for MCMC chains based on the data
    low, med, high = np.percentile(data, (16, 50, 84))
    mu_init = np.float32(med)
    t_init = np.float32(np.log(0.5 * (high - low)))

    def model(data_shape):
        mu = ed.Uniform(low=-1.0, high=1.0, name="mu")
        t = ed.Uniform(low=tf.log(0.05), high=tf.log(1.0), name="t")
        x = ed.Normal(
            loc=tf.fill(data_shape, mu), scale=tf.fill(data_shape, tf.exp(t)), name="x"
        )
        return x

    log_joint = ed.make_log_joint_fn(model)

    def target_log_prob_fn(mu, t):
        """Target log-probability as a function of states."""
        return log_joint(data.shape, mu=mu, t=t, x=data)

    step_size = tf.get_variable(
        name='step_size',
        initializer=0.01,
        use_resource=True,  # For TFE compatibility
        trainable=False,
    )

    num_burnin_steps = 1000

    hmc_kernel = tfp.mcmc.HamiltonianMonteCarlo(
        target_log_prob_fn=target_log_prob_fn,
        num_leapfrog_steps=5,
        step_size=step_size,
        step_size_update_fn=tfp.mcmc.make_simple_step_size_update_policy(
            num_adaptation_steps=int(num_burnin_steps * 0.8)
        ),
    )

    # Initial states of chains
    q_mu = tf.reduce_mean(tf.random_normal((1000,), mean=mu_init))
    q_t = tf.reduce_mean(tf.random_normal((1000,), mean=t_init))

    states, kernel_results = tfp.mcmc.sample_chain(
        num_results=n_samples,
        current_state=[q_mu, q_t],
        kernel=hmc_kernel,
        num_burnin_steps=num_burnin_steps,
    )

    # Initialize all constructed variables.
    init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()

    # Run the inference using HMC to generate samples
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        init_op.run()
        states_, results_ = sess.run([states, kernel_results])
        mu_samples, t_samples = (states_[0], states_[1])

    return mu_samples, t_samples


def visualize(samples, mu_grid, sigma_grid):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(6, 5))
    ax.scatter(samples['mu'], samples['sigma'], s=5, lw=0, c='black')
    ax.set_xlim(mu_grid[0], mu_grid[-1])
    ax.set_ylim(sigma_grid[0], sigma_grid[-1])
    ax.set_title('tfp and Edward2')
    ax.set_xlabel('$\mu$')
    ax.set_ylabel('$\sigma$')
    plt.savefig('tfp-edward2.pdf')
    plt.savefig('tfp-edward2.png')


def main():
    np.random.seed(0)
    tf.set_random_seed(0)

    # Generate pseudodata from draws from a single normal distribution
    dist_mean = 0.0
    dist_std = 0.5
    n_events = 5000
    toy_data = scipy.stats.norm.rvs(dist_mean, dist_std, size=n_events)

    mu_samples, t_samples = generate_samples(toy_data, n_events)
    samples = pd.DataFrame({'mu': mu_samples, 'sigma': np.exp(t_samples)})

    n_grid = 50
    mu_grid = np.linspace(*np.percentile(mu_samples, (0.5, 99.5)), n_grid)
    sigma_grid = np.linspace(*np.exp(np.percentile(t_samples, (0.5, 99.5))), n_grid)
    visualize(samples, mu_grid, sigma_grid)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```